# Unable to access my files created by me or added by me on googledrive from google API having scope as drive.file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, vs-web-application-project

the drive.file scope is restricting the scope of the app to only the files created or opened by the app but the files shared or added to the folder created by app is not accessible,
Whereas drive as a scope gives the full access to the entire drive of the user and which is the restricted scope.

Is there any middle way between these scope to access the file inside the folder created by the app?.

If not then may be Google should think on it because in either of the way user have to comprise either on the privacy or on the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately right now there are no scopes allowing you a middle way in-between.

However, you are not the only one interested in this feature, on Google's Public Issue tracker, there are already [several feature requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%20%20type:feature_request%20scope) to implement more scoeps for the Drive API.

I recommend you to find the feature request that best corresponds to your needs and give it a "star". The more people star an issue, the more Google will be aware of the importance and urgency of a feature request.

Comment: Thanks ziganotschka, will check the feature request. But what about a google.picker for it .

Comment: I am not very familiar with the google.picker api, but I believe that it uses the same drive scopes as the drive API and does not have its own scopes.